# how many core should i have to used for indexing 50 millions of documents using Solr

Tags: solr, solrj, dih

I have a 40 millions of files which is stored in a file systems. 
I want to take Some suggestion, there are so many method to do indexing such as DIH, solr, Solrj. 
How many core should I use for indexing 50 millions of documents.
I have 40 millions of documents.

I have decided to do using SolJ. Is this a good way to that thing, if yes then I don't know how many core should I use?

I have a 40 millions of files which is stored in a file systems, 
the filename saved as ARIA_SSN10_0007_LOCATION_0000129.pdf

1. I have to split all underscore value from a filename and these value have to be index to the solr.

The above operation I have to do. Is it opssible using DIH if yes then  How I will split these operation using DIH. Please share some link for it.

please suggest. 
Thanks

Comment: check if this is of any help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691606/solr-multicore-vs-sharding-vs-1-big-collection/31691754#31691754

Comment: @Abhijit I saw your post  have you indexing these core using SolrJ ?

Comment: no. I am not using SolrJ...Using the http/Rest API's of solr...indexing by DIH..

Comment: I have a file systems, the filename saved as ARIA_SSN10_0007_LOCATION_0000129.pdf and I have to split all underscore value from a filename and these value have to be index to the solr. how would do these thing like split etc using DIH Is This possible using DIH if Yes then how

Comment: splitting the text is whats is called as tokenizing the text... and that is done with the help of analyser/tokenizers and filters etc.... so build s fieldType or use existing one for the your field...

Comment: splitting the text not like that way...i think you didn't read my requirement. i have to split filename get lots of value these values i have to index corresponding to their field...Please read my requirement.. before indexing i want to fetch value then index to solr.. How to do it with use of DIH ?